# How to connect 16 gauge wire to DRV8825?

Tags: current, circuit-design, connector, pins, awg

I need to connect 16 gauge wire to one of the pins of my DRV8825 motor driver. I know DuPont cables are not going to work because they typically max out at 5 amps. What else can I use? Also, is it possible that I could use a smaller gauge wire because the motor driver only outputs 2.5 amps max, which would allow me to use a different wire, but other components in my circuit might draw currents of 12 amps.

My circuit is depicted below
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is stopping you from using 16 gauge wire? Why would other parts of the circuit that can draw 12A affect the choice of wire on the drv8825?

Comment: @Kartman That's exactly my question. If my drv8825 will only ever use 2.5 amps of current but other parts of my circuit use more do I have to use 16 gauge wire because the other parts of my circuit are using more current?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wire you used should be sized for the current you are running on that single section of wire. From your schematic, as hard to read as it is, you have multiple power cables  going to individual devices and some cables for control signals. A basic star topology. So the connection from the power supply to the motor and back could be 20 AWG for that single 2.5A load (depends on the load AND the cable length, the resistance adds up and voltage drop happens as it increases). And the 4A load may need 18 AWG, etc.

Now if you have a section that goes from the power supply to multiple loads, then that section would need a thicker wire than the section that only covers a small load.

Use a wire gauge calculator online to find out the best size to use.